# problem with spaces added while running queries with the teradatasql package

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata

While comparing two methods to run Teradata queries under Python, I noticed that the one using teradatasql adds spaces to columns of type varchar.

**Method 1 (no spaces added)**

```
import teradata
import pandas 

... #defining connection credentials
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appConfigFile = ConfigPath, 
     logFile = LogPath, logLevel = LogLev, logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method = 'odbc', system = hostname, 
     username= usn, password=pwd,driver = drv)

output = pandas.read_sql(query, session)
```

**Method 2 (spaces added)**

```
import teradatasql
import pandas

... #defining connection credentials
with teradatasql.connect (host = hostname, user= usn, password= pwd) as conn:
   output = pandas.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Could you kindly help me find a way to fix this issue ?

Comment: I suspect the padding is actually for columns of type CHAR not VARCHAR. The padding is a consequence of `teradatasql` always using UTF8 session character set (which is inherently variable length) while with the ODBC driver you are apparently defaulting to (fixed-length) ASCII session character set. You could TRIM the CHAR columns in the query (which makes the result VARCHAR) to eliminate the padding.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Fred's analysis. The Character Export Width issue is documented here: https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver#CharacterExportWidth